# Unable to delete data from a MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am unable to delete data from my database. This is my code:

```
Dim DeleteData As OleDbCommand

conn.open()
sql1 = ("DELETE FROM Etat_projet WHERE Nom_du_client= &TextBox1.Text")

DeleteData = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn)
DeleteData.ExecuteNonQuery()
Me.Close()
```

This is a capture of my database and the record still exists:

[image]

Comment: One idea would be to read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Try to use OleDbConnection.

Comment: Fast guess: `"DELETE FROM Etat_projet WHERE Nom_du_client= &TextBox1.Text"` => change it to `"DELETE FROM Etat_projet WHERE Nom_du_client='" &TextBox1.Text & "'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `TextBox1.Text` as a parameter into the command like so:

```
sql1 = "DELETE FROM Etat_projet WHERE Nom_du_client = ?"
DeleteData = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn)
DeleteData.Parameters.Add("@Nom", OleDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBox1.Text
DeleteData.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

> Note that I have used `OleDbType.[Type]`. You will want to replace this with the data type you have specified for your columns.

I would also consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString),
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Etat_projet WHERE Nom_du_client = ?", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nom", OleDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```